# How to model transition matrix in indirect kalman filter with external orientation estimate

Tags: kalman-filter, sensor-fusion

I am trying to implement an indirect/error state kalman filter following [Quaternion kinematics for the error-state Kalman filter](http://www.iri.upc.edu/people/jsola/JoanSola/objectes/notes/kinematics.pdf).
However, instead of modelling the orientation and error in orientation I have chosen to [utilize Madwick](http://x-io.co.uk/res/doc/madgwick_internal_report.pdf) to estimate the orientation.

The problem is that when I create the transition matrix from the [first paper](http://www.iri.upc.edu/people/jsola/JoanSola/objectes/notes/kinematics.pdf) it expects the orientation error which it multiplies with the skew matrix of the measured acceleration and the accelerometer bias (page 40, equation 204). Since I have removed that from my states I can't use it, but then the measured acceleration is never considered (which I assume makes the filter worse). Is there any change I can make to the transition matrix so that it accounts for the acceleration?

Comment: "Instead of modelling the orientation and error in orientation I have chose to utilize [the Madwick filter]." What are you trying to measure with your filter, then?

Comment: Position, velocity and other factors. I have only removed orientation and gyroscope bias (since the Madwick filter accounts for bias). My thinking is that the Madwick filter is more than enough to model orientation, but I want position and velocity as well and so keep those state in the filter.

Comment: The Madgwick filter gives you position.

Comment: How does it do that? As far as I can see the only state that is kept in the paper is orientation, it also has no way of incorporating additional data like GPS or vision.

Answer (score 1):

After careful reading of the first paper I think the solution to the problem is to simply not include the multiplication. From the proof of 172b and equation 177, in my filter I have $R_t$ (since I get that from the Madgwick filter) and can simply apply that to the error state. So equation 195b is instead $\delta v  = \delta v - (R\delta a_b - \delta g)\Delta t + \mathbf{v_i}$, note that we don't multiply with $\theta$ since the Madgwick filter models that error.

The transition matrix does then not have to include any terms related to $\theta$ which means we only relate error in speed with error in accelerometer $\delta a_b$ and error in the gravity vector $\delta g$. In essence we remove the skew matrix multiplication.

Edit: I will hold of accepting this answer either until I have a chance to try the improvement or until someone else can vouch for it. Other answers are very welcome!